# How to download multiple files in nightmare js

Tags: javascript, node.js, headless-browser, nightmare

So I've got this set up

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare');
require('nightmare-inline-download')(Nightmare);
require('nightmare-download-manager')(Nightmare);

const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: false, waitTimeout: 2500, gotoTimeout: 5000 });

var download = ( async () => {
    const url = "someurl"

    nightmare.on('download', function(state, downloadItem){
        if(state == 'started'){
            nightmare.emit('download', downloadItem.filename, downloadItem);
        }
    });

    let test = nightmare
        .downloadManager()
        .goto(url, {Authorization: "Basic"})
        .wait("#summary-val")
        .evaluate( () => {
            document.querySelectorAll("#attachments li .attachment-thumb a").forEach( function(elem) {
                elem.click()
            })
        })
        .waitDownloadsComplete()
        .end()
        .then(data => {
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Search failed:', error);
        });
})

download();
```

However this only downloads the last file. Doing a `click("#attachments li .attachment-thumb a")` results in only the first file being downloaded.

So how can I make this recursively download all the files?